# Feature request: change "modified" to a more descriptive word.

Tags: discussion, feature-request

On the [active](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) list, I would like to see more descriptive language used in place of "modified."

Instead of saying "modified N hours ago," it would be helpful if instead it said 
"**edited** N hours ago," 
"**retagged** N hours ago," 
"**asked** N hours ago," 
or "**answered** N hours ago."

(An additional feature could be the option to filter by the type of modification, e.g. to display only answers or only retags.)

Would others find this feature useful?

Comment: Related: [Feature request: newest answers list](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/feature-request-newest-answers-list) and [Should retagging not move questions to the top of the active list?](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/should-retagging-not-move-questions-to-the-top-of-the-active-list)

Comment: Although Meta.UX is fine for such questions, and ux.se should be able to be thought of as a site in its own right, if you're looking for feature requests for how the *StackExchange engine itself* works then you'll probably get better luck over on the main http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ site for such things. it might be worth re-asking / cross-posting that there to get the feedback of the whole stackexchange community. But still leave this open here, as it'll be interesting to get ux.se users opinions.

Comment: @JonW  Thanks for the suggestion.  I've [crossposted on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183137/change-modified-to-a-more-descriptive-word).