# Feature request: newest answers list

Tags: discussion, feature-request

At the moment, we have an option to list the [newest questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), why not have one to list the newest answers as well?

This feature would be **beneficial** for two reasons:

1. It would benefit users who come to the site during a brief break, **looking to learn something, but without enough time to post an answer** (and thus not wanting to look at the recent unanswered questions).  With the current setup, such users have to slog through a mishmash of edits, retags, questions, and answers on the [active list](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) or else clicking through various [newest questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) to find actual new content to read.
2. Allowing users to view a list of recent answers could help to **revive older questions**.  Oftentimes new responses to old questions get pushed down the *active list* so quickly that they go largely unnoticed, but listing recent answers on their own list (or even giving an option to list recent answers to old questions) would help to make sure that such answers are not overlooked.

I expect that because there are already six ways to view posts (newest, featured, frequent, votes, active, unanswered) on the [questions page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions) and five (active, featured, hot, week, month) on the [main page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/), people might be reluctant to add another.  Instead of adding a *newest answers* list on the questions page, **three alternative solutions** to the problem of being unable easily to view recent answers could be:

1. Add an option to **search** for answers, including for answers to questions older than a certain time. [EDIT: The option to search for answers exists, even though it's not possible to filter them by question.]
2. Change the *active* page to use [**alternatives to the word *modified***](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/feature-request-change-modified-to-a-more-descriptive-word).   (This feature would be beneficial regardless of whether there's any consensus about a need for a *newest answers* list.)
3. **Highlight** any entry on the newest questions list that has answers you haven't yet read.

**Would you also be interested in having a recent answers list?**

Comment: This is more of a hack than anything, but this is effectively the same information: [searching for all answers, ordered by newest](http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aa)

Comment: Ah!  That's very helpful.  I'd completely overlooked the advanced search options on the right-hand-side of the [search page](http://ux.stackexchange.com/search).  I still think an inbuilt recent-answers-list would be a useful feature though.

Comment: @BenBrocka That is nice!  I think that would be useful as a view instead of a query in the search.